# set custom parameters in xmlhttprequest object and then accessing inside success function in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am setting some custom object in XMLHttpRequest object in Jquery. Here is my code:

```
$.ajax({
    url : APP_PATH + "/users/update?" + urlParams,
    datatype : 'json',
    async : false,
    custom_rowid : rowid,
    custom_action : action,
    success: function (jsondata) {
        console.log($(this));
        console.log("Row Id - " + $($(this)).custom_rowid);
        console.log("Action - " + $($(this)).custom_action);
    }
});
```

I get values for `custom_rowid` and `custom_action` inside `success` function as `undefined`. While, when I check the `$(this)`, it has the corresponding attributes set.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Why are you using $($(this))? That is the same thing as $(this).

Comment: Actually, I was thinking it is not able to pick the data from the object, so wrapped it again in jquery selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The context for the success handler is the `settings` object, so it should just be:

```
success: function (jsondata) {
    console.log("Row Id - " + this.custom_rowid);
    console.log("Action - " + this.custom_action);
}
```

From the jQuery documentation for [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

> The `this` reference within all callbacks is the object in the `context`
>   option passed to `$.ajax` in the settings; if `context` is not specified,
>   `this` is a reference to the Ajax settings themselves.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a property of the object, try using the .prop() method to access it.

```
$(this).prop("custom_rowid");
$(this).prop("custom_action");
```